# How to get video pre roll ads through admob?

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-services

Are there pre-roll video ads with the latest play services api? I can see this [admob interstitial ad tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced) . But, it gives full screen interstitial ad with a close button. I want to have video ads like in youtube. It should come and go away without user interaction. Am I missing it somewhere here?

Comment: Did you able to find solution? I an through same situation.